# i just want to add my session values in array but it display only the last elememt here is my code

Tags: php, arrays, session

I just want to add my session values in array but it displays only the last element. Here is my code

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_item)
    {
        $p_name = $cart_item["info2"];

    }
    echo $p_name;
}

$product_files[] = array( 
    'name' => $p_name,
    'filename' => $p_name,
    'source'=> $c_path                                                                               );
```

Comment: That's because you use `echo $p_name` after the `foreach` loop. And what`s in `$cart_item["info2"]`? An array?

Comment: do you use **session_start()** ?

Comment: you did echo $cart_item["info2"]; after that creating an array. what do you actually want to print?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) {
 $args = array();
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_item){
   $args[] = $cart_item["info2"];
 }
 print_r($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

```
         if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) {
            $p_name = array();

            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_item)
            {

                $p_name = $cart_item["info2"];
                  $product_files[] = array( 
                    'name' => $p_name ,
                    'filename' => $p_name,
                    'source'=> $c_path);
            }      
        }
```

**updated $product_files inside loop**